# Order of Image of Semidirect Product under Left Regular Representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Consider the group $G:=A⋊_{f}B$. Let $G$ act on the set of left cosets for $B$, inducing the permutation representation $\theta:G→S_n$.

**Can we conclude that $|\theta(G)|=|\theta(A)||\theta(B)|$?**

Comment: In general, the kernel of $\theta$ is equal to the kernel of $f$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Right, that's true. So we know that $f$ is injective iff $\theta$ is, right? Would this fact help answer my question? Do we need to know that $f$ is injective for the claim to hold?

Comment: Fore the claim to hold you just need $\theta(A) \cap \theta(B) = 1$, which is always true because for $a \in A \setminus \{ 1\}$ $\theta(a)$ has no fixed points, but $\theta(b)$ has the fixed point $B$ for all $b \in B$. So the claim is always true and my previous remark is not directoly relevant.

Comment: @DerekHolt This makes sense. Thank you!